# Getting a java.lang.indexoutofboundsexception, but no idea why?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
List<String> s = getConfig().getStringList("clanowner");
if (!(s.isEmpty())) {

    for (String str : s) {
        String[] words = str.split(":");
        menu.clanowner.put(words[0], words[1]);
    }
}
```

So, I am getting a java.lang.indexoutofboundsexception, but I have no idea why this is happening. Will somebody please help me?

Comment: If the `words[]` array only contains one element, `words[1]` will not exist (out of bounds). What does the exact stack trace say?

Comment: The split function is probably returning an array with one element not two.

Comment: Use a debugger and you will see exactly why.

Comment: Thanks @Alex I added a try and catch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch is that

```
String[] words = str.split(":");
```

is probably not returning an array of length 2.  Changing the last line of the for statement to

```
if(words != null && words.length > 1) {
    menu.clanowner.put(words[0], words[1]);
}
```

should eliminate the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

As a debugging practice, it also helps to know exactly what it going in there, so make sure that

```
List<String> s = getConfig().getStringList("clanowner");
```

truly is giving you output that should produce arrays of length 2 or more either by debugging or manually inserting values that should work, or both.